# How to check if the user enters the default datetime?

Tags: vb.net

I have two textboxes on the screen. They are used for startdate and enddate. If the user does not enter anything in the textboxes I pass nothing (VB.NET) to the webservice. When the webservice receive it on the other end it shows the value "#12:00:00 AM" which I think is the default for the datetime field. Anyway, now I do not want to pass this value to Stored procedure since it will not work. How can I check before sending values to sproc that the value is not the default datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to pass it to the WebService, why do you pass it anyway?

To see if a Date is not the "default-date":

```
If Not Date.MinValue = MyDate
```

Comment: I have to pass something to the webservice since it is one of the parameters. So I pass null or nothing and it ends up being "#12:00:00 AM".

Comment: @John: ok, i understand. You can check for `Date.MinValue` as i've mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options here.

1. Since you already know that you're receiving "#12:00:00AM" when the field is not filled in, check if the value you receive is "#12:00:00AM".
2. Prior to passing the value to your stored procedure, create a new DateTime object.  Compare the value you're receiving against the value in the new DateTime object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of DateTime use Nullable of DateTime.  Then you can pass a null (or nothing) value to the web service and you use Date.HasValue to check if a value was entered/passed.